# how do i implement a model in my streamlit application

Tags: machine-learning, streamlit, encoder, custom-training

i have cloned a GitHub rep and used it to produce real time voice cloning. It is  working ..i am executing commands in cmd..for getting the real time voice cloning of my voice. Now I want the model to train on my voice and i want to use it for my project which should be in a streamlit application. Firstly i don't know whether the model will be trained itself when it gave tts in my voice ..but it didn't undergo a training process using my voice dataset. Rather I gave a single recording and from if. It generated voice for the input text. Secondly if it is trained how can I use that model.

i tried to check if the models will save the synthesized voice and i tried to implement the model but i keep getting error saying no module found. But i added it to my path. it is still showing error.i am so confused

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.